# Opencv4nodejs limit size of video capture

Tags: node.js, opencv, nestjs

I'm trying to use opencv4nodejs to serve webcam footage to a webpage encoded in base64

I can't reliably get opencv to poll the camera at more than 10fps. I believe this is due to performance reasons

I want to limit the size of the frame to help. I'm using

```
this.cvCap.set(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,300);
this.cvCap.set(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,300);
```

But when I use these commands I get the following error

```
/home/brandonp/repos/nestwebcam/dist/webcam/webcam.service.js:30
            const image = cv.imencode(".jpg", frame).toString('base64');
                             ^
Io::Imencode - OpenCV Error: (Raw image encoder error: Empty JPEG image (DNL not supported)) in throwOnEror, in file /home/brandonp/repos/nestwebcam/node_modules/opencv-build/opencv/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/grfmt_base.cpp, line 145, status -10
(Use `node --trace-uncaught ...` to show where the exception was thrown)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is due to, your camera disconnected or not readable. Please check if your camera is working or not using the command `raspistill -o testshot.jpg`

Comment: I found that It was actually a problem with the hardware of my camera, It's only able to capture at 10fps. That being said, If I wanted to lower the resolution for whatever reason these commands still throw this error